# Adding a Back Button on Android Activity Page having Intent

Tags: android, navigation, android-intent, back

I am a newbie to Android development. I want to plot a Line Chart and have used achartengine to draw the Chart. I got success in drawing the graph.

The issue now am facing is I have an application where this chart is to be added with a "BACK" button on the top of the chart.

My Code is as under

```
public class Demo extends Activity {
    Intent intent = null;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        intent = new MyChart().execute(getApplicationContext());
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Below is the code which executes the Graph

```
public class MyChart extends AbstractDemoChart {
    public Intent execute(Context context) {
        ...
        ...
        ...
        ...
        ...
        return ChartFactory.getTimeChartIntent(context,buildDateDataset(titles, tempDatesList, weightList), renderer, format);
    }
}
```

Now I want to add an xml file in /layout/main.xml where in the chart would be drawn and with a back button added somewhere on the top with the entire chart below it.. Please help me

Comment: For what purpose do you need the back button? Every Android Device comes with a "hardware" back button that allows the user to go back to the previous screen

Answer (score 1):

You can use a linear or relative layout. In that place a button named "Back" and below it place the xml layout for the chart. And also use setContentView(R.layout.main) in your activity class(Demo Class).

Comment: Thanks fr ur effort. Can U please elaborate more on the same so that I can reach to the solution in a positive manner... If u need my code can also give it to you for your reference. Please, Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You can add a button, and just call `finish();` to finish the Activity when the button is clicked. When you are finishing the activity, it will load the previous activity which was executing.

Comment: Thanks for your effort. I had tried this way also but the button is not getting displayed somehow the chart is taking the entire screen.